# Setting Xcode capabilities

Tags: xcode7

When setting the capabilities for things like Maps (as shown below), what does it actually do behind the scene? How can we do the same programatically without setting it in Capabilities?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Setting capabilities adds entries to the info.plist and links the necessary framework to the project.  In this case, it adds MKDirectionsApplicationSupportedModes and links MapKit to the project.